# function not returning whole value to main

Tags: c

I am trying to get my function to return the value of M to main, but it doesn't return the full value. for example, M = 397.73, but when called to print in main, it only returns 397.00.
The input I am trying to use is 100000, 2.55, 30. So that is why my expected output is 397.73.

```
int main(void) {
  int loanAmount;
  double APR;
  int time;
  double M;


  printf("Enter in loan amount:\n");
  scanf("%d", &loanAmount);
  printf("Enter APR: \n");
  scanf("%lf", &APR);
  printf("Enter loan time (years): \n");
  scanf("%d", &time);
  printf("Loan amount: %7d\nAPR: %13.2f%%\nTime of loan: %d years\n", loanAmount, APR, time);
  M = CalculatePayment(M, loanAmount, APR, time);
  printf("%.2lf", M); //This is where my issue comes from, this only prints partial of M.

  return 0;
}





int CalculatePayment(double M, int P, double c, int d) {
  //M= P * r(1+r)^n/(1+r)^n-1
  int n = d * 12; //number of months of loan.
  double IM = (c / 100) / 12; //monthly interest rate.
  M = P * ((IM  * pow(1 + IM, n)) / (pow(1+IM, n) - 1)); // calculates monthly payment.
  printf("%.2lf\n", M);
  return M;
}
```

Comment: You've declared it to return an *int*, and it's doing what you told it to do.

Comment: And what is the purpose of the parameter `M` to `CalculatePayment`? You pass it an uninitialized value, and then you never use it.

Answer (score 7):

The return type of `CalculatePayment` is `int`, so the return value is truncated to integer.

Use `double` as the return type instead.

Comment: It also needs a function declaration. Without one, MS Visual C says *warning C4013: 'CalculatePayment' undefined; assuming extern returning int*, and then *error C2371: 'CalculatePayment': redefinition; different basic types.*

Comment: @WeatherVane `#include <stdio.h>` is also required.

Comment: And `math.h` too.

Answer (score 3):

Change the return type of the function to double. It now returns int as it is declared to return int. And since you then assign the result to a double, it gets automatically converted back to double, but without the fraction part, since ints have no fraction parts.

It should be:

```
double CalculatePayment (double M, int P, double c, int d)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you made a slight typo, you must have meant `double CalculatePayment(...)`

Comment: Ah, but you should probably put the actual parameters of the function too as opposed to `void`. <EDIT> just saw the fix, thanks for fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

`CalculatePayment()` returns an `int`.  You need it to return `double`.  Also you unnecessarily passing `M` as a parameter:

```
double CalculatePayment( int P, double c, int d ) 
{
  int n = d * 12;              // number of months of loan.
  double IM = (c / 100) / 12;  // monthly interest rate.

  // calculate monthly payment.
  return P * ((IM  * pow(1 + IM, n)) / (pow(1+IM, n) - 1)); 
}
```

Then call:

```
M = CalculatePayment( loanAmount, APR, time ) ;
```